# Weblogic 10.3.5 Web app startup error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to deploy a web app into Weblogic 10.3.5 and when I try to start the application I'm getting the following error:

```
####<Oct 29, 2012 5:27:12 AM PDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <ip-0A2E9E72> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> 
<<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1351513632838> <BEA-101162> 
<User defined listener artemispm.web.ui.gwt.server.A7WebStartupListener failed: java.lang.NullPointerException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:143)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:729)
```

The error above is caused by the following code excerpt which is part of a ServiceContextListener class implementation:

```
System.setProperty(A7WebConstants.PROP_OUTPUT_DIR_PATH, outputDirPath);
```

The outputDirPath variable is not null so does any one know what is going down here? I'm using JDK6 and the application runs pretty fine on Tomcat 6 and 7 as well. Also, I haven't changed any configurations in web.xml file.

**UPDATED:

I just have noticed that when I try to deploy my app I get this error, before the above one:

```
####<Oct 29, 2012 7:03:25 AM PDT> <Error> <Console> <ip-0A2E9E72> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <9fceb15ac10fa447:5dceb4c5:13aac5c55aa:-7ff7-0000000000000005> <1351519405088> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Getting Deployment configuration...
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:911)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.isSchemaBased(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:1930)
at com.bea.console.actions.app.DeploymentPlanAction.execute(DeploymentPlanAction.java:136)
```

Thank you,

Gyo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess is that key is null then because `java.util.Properties.set` is using `HashTable.put` operation, see javadoc: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put%28K,%20V%29

If this is not the case, could you check what `System.getProperty("dummy")` returns? 
If props in code snippet below is null (from java source code) then the above would also throw `NullPointer`.

```
package java.lang;
...
import java.util.Properties;
...
private static Properties props;
....
public static String setProperty(String key, String value) {
checkKey(key);
SecurityManager sm = getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
    sm.checkPermission(new PropertyPermission(key,
    SecurityConstants.PROPERTY_WRITE_ACTION));
}

return (String) props.setProperty(key, value); //line 729
}
```

Comment: Hi Daljiian thanks for your reply. I have updated my question with further information. Now I'm seeing that there is an error while the app is being deployed, so it's before the null pointer error. Do you have any thoughts on that?